# Computing $\ E[|X-Y|^a] $ for $\ X, Y \sim U(0, 1) $

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $\ X, Y \sim U(0,1) $ be random independent variables.

How do I prove that: $$\ \text{E}[|X-Y|^a] = \frac{2}{(a+1)(a+2)} $$

my attempt is to split it to two parts in order to get rid of absolute value function. My problem is setting the integral limits.

$$\ E[|X-Y|^a] = \int \int (x-y)^a dy dx + \int \int (y-x)^a dx dy $$

Where first part is where $\ x > y $ and the second part is $\ y > x $.

$$\ \int \int (x-y)^a f_y f_x \ dy \ dx \
\\ $$

I tried to set the $\ y $ integral from $\ 0 $ to some value $\ k $ and then $\ x $ integrate from $\ k $ to $\ 1 $ and then do vice versa on the second part.

Didn't work though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in splitting the integral. The only error that I see is in the limits for $x$. This is what I think should lead you to the correct answer.

$$I_1 = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^x(x-y)^a dy dx$$

Since $y<x$, $y$ integrates from $0$ to $x$. However, when you integrate $x$, it should be allowed to take all the values between $0$ and $1$. Hence, $I_1 = \frac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)}$ and so is the other integral. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the same answer as yours for $\ I_1 $ but with a negative sign... Trying to figure out if something missing here?

Comment: There will be negative sign in the inner integral since you are integrating w.r.t. $y$. This is because $y$ has a negative sign in the integral.